NetBoxをECS on fargateでデプロイしようとすると RDSのログにcould not accept SSL connection: EOF detectedというエラーがでる
私は NetBox をECS(fargate)で構築しようとしていて、具体的な構成としてはデータベースはRDS(PostgreSQL)、キャッシュサーバはElastiCache(Redis)で進めています。目標としては下記のリンクのような構成を目指しているのですが上手く起動しません。
NetBox のオンプレから Amazon ECS 移植を CDK で実現する
※CDKで実装するのではなくAWSマネジメントコンソールから実装しようとしています。
必要な情報を設定してデプロイしたのですがRDSのログで下記のようなエラーがでてしまいます。
:LOG: could not accept SSL connection: EOF detected

NetBoxのテーブル自体はECSのサービス起動時に作成されたので問題なくやりとりが行われていると考えているのですが、どのように対処すればよいか教えていただきたいです。
情報
PostgreSQL 16.3
試したこと

セキュリティグループの見直し
ECSのタスク定義の見直し(エンドポイント名やパスワード名、ポートが間違えていないか)
RDSのパラメータグループの rds.force.ssl を1→0に変更
ECSの環境変数で DB_SSLMODE=disable に変更

